# Android Kotlin: fetching image from directory

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am building an app with Kotlin frontend/Python backend. My python script creates a .png file under getFilesDir() directory (/data/user/0/com.example.myproject/files/mygraph.png). I then want to use kotlin to fetch the .png file and display it on imageview.

Believe I have to use Bitmap but am not familiar with it so your support is much appreciated.

```
class Graph : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph)

        val dir = "/data/user/0/com.example.myproject/files/mygraph.png"
        //Bitmap function

    }
}
```

Comment: The answer below is creating a new `ImageView` that isn't attached to the `Activity`, so you'll never see it. If you have an `<ImageView>` in the `activity_graph` layout already, then you can just use that with the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` they demonstrate. That will load on the main thread, though, so your UI will hang a bit. It'd be preferable to do that on a separate thread, or you could use an image loading library that will do it for you; e.g., Glide, Picasso, Coil, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BitmapFactory` to decode file path

```
    val imageView = ImageView(this)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath))
```

Comment: thank you. Now how can I assign that value to imageview? I have an imageview id graphRes want to display it there.

Comment: just use your ```graphRes```  imageView in place of my imageView

Comment: Tried that but i get a blank image instead. I dont get error message btw.

Comment: Check your filepath

Comment: .png file exists on the folder path but I still cannot fetch the graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214960/discussion-between-krishna-sony-and--).